# How can I select a row in 2 DataGridViews when selected in a third DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have 3 DataGridViews.
With DataGridView1 and DataGridView2 you can select rows. 
After pushing a button the rows from DataGridView1 and DataGridView2 are compared and every row that has the same values are set in DataGridView3.

What I want is when you select a row in DataGridView3, the same rows are selected in DataGridView1 and DataGridView2.

The code I have, and also works is:

```
private int ShowSelected(int selectedId, Boolean sBool)
{
    DataTable dt = DataGridView1.DataSource;

    if(!sBool)
        currentGrid = DataGridView1;


    int indexCounter = 0;            
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            int cellIdDgv = Convert.ToInt32(dr["cellId"]);

                if (selectedId == cellIdDgv)
                {
                    if (sBool)
                    {
                        DataGridView1.Rows[indexCounter].Selected = true;
                        DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell = DataGridView1.Rows[indexCounter].Cells[0];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DataGridView2.Rows[indexCounter].Selected = true;
                        DataGridView2.FirstDisplayedCell = DataGridView2.Rows[indexCounter].Cells[0];
                    }
                }

        indexCounter++;
    }
}
```

But what I want is something like this, so you don't have to loop through the whole Grid:

```
string selection = "cellId = " + selectedId;
DataRow[] drResult = dt.Select(selection);
int rowId  = drResult.RowId;

if (sBool)
{
    DataGridView1.Rows[rowId].Selected = true;
        DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell = DataGridView1.Rows[rowId].Cells[0];
}
else
{
    DataGridView2.Rows[rowId].Selected = true;
        DataGridView2.FirstDisplayedCell = DataGridView2.Rows[rowId].Cells[0];
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: You could use a [`BindingSource.Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx). This would enable you to filter on the third `DataGridView`. The link also has examples.

Answer (score 0):

To extend on my comment and to provide a local (stackoverflow) solution:

Filtering is accomplished using the [`BindingSource.Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx) property. The example provided on MSDN is:

```
    private void PopulateDataViewAndFilter()
    {
        DataSet set1 = new DataSet();

        // Some xml data to populate the DataSet with.
        string musicXml =
             "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" +
             "<music>" +
             "<recording><artist>Coldplay</artist><cd>X&amp;Y</cd></recording>" +
             "<recording><artist>Dave Matthews</artist><cd>Under the Table and Dreaming</cd></recording>" +
             "<recording><artist>Dave Matthews</artist><cd>Live at Red Rocks</cd></recording>" +
             "<recording><artist>Natalie Merchant</artist><cd>Tigerlily</cd></recording>" +
             "<recording><artist>U2</artist><cd>How to Dismantle an Atomic Bomb</cd></recording>" +
             "</music>";

        // Read the xml.
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(musicXml);
        set1.ReadXml(reader);

        // Get a DataView of the table contained in the dataset.
        DataTableCollection tables = set1.Tables;
        DataView view1 = new DataView(tables[0]);

        // Create a DataGridView control and add it to the form.
        DataGridView datagridview1 = new DataGridView();
        datagridview1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        this.Controls.Add(datagridview1);

        // Create a BindingSource and set its DataSource property to
        // the DataView.
        BindingSource source1 = new BindingSource();
        source1.DataSource = view1;

        // Set the data source for the DataGridView.
        datagridview1.DataSource = source1;

        //The Filter string can include Boolean expressions.
        source1.Filter = "artist = 'Dave Matthews' OR cd = 'Tigerlily'";
    }
```

To make it easier, you may want to create a `FilterBuilder`.

Edit: To avoid filtering or the above looping mentioned in your question, create a `DataTable` using a `BindingSource` etc. which is linked to your `DataGridView1 then:

```
DataTable DT; // Obtained from the relevent DGV.
DataView view = new DataView(DT);
DataView thisDV = new DataView();

// Then you can use...
thisDV.Find(thisOrThat);
thisDV.FindRows(thisOrThat);
```

To find the relevant rows in the data, this can then be used to feed a `Selection()` in you `DataGridView`s.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't select the already existing datarow, this put NEW data into my DataGridView, if I understand?

Comment: You can create filter on the relevent `DataGridView` (selected by any event you wish - `CellClick` on another `DataGridView` etc.) and use this to filter the relevent records.

Comment: But I still don't get it. How does this select the rows in my 2 grids?

Comment: Ok. So if I have understood correctly; you want to use the selection from one `DataGridView` (DGV), call it DGV A to filter/select data from the the two other DGVs (DGV B and C). So, set up an `EventHandler` upon the `CellClick` event for grid A (using the `EventArgs` get the relevant cell clicked upon). In this event create two filters for each of the other grids (B and C) using a `BindingSource` as per the examle above. Establish the data you wish to filter on by using the value in the clicked cell of DGV A and use it to create filters to filter/select the relevent results in grids B and C.

Comment: What I want is showed in the first code example. When you select a row in grid3 the data is also selected in grid1 and grid2. Grid1 and grid2 already have data and it's not suppose to be changed. It's only possible to select one row in grid3 because multiselect is false. The problem I have in my second example code is that RowId is an non-public member.

Comment: So all the working eventhandlers for the gridviews are already there.

Comment: Oh, ok. SO you can't change the format of the DGVs. Right well, you should get the cell contents of DGV A via the `CellClick` event (convert to striing or what ever is neccessary), then get the data as a `DataView` and use that to locate the required froms in DGV B and C. Then just use the `Select` method to get the cells. I have updated the answer...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't see how I can get the rowId via this code?